# ColdFusion cfoutput & excluding items

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

```
 <cfif dir.name IS NOT "Thumbs.db">
```

This code excludes `Thumbs.db` from being called in the cfoutput query, but what if I want another file excluded? Not sure how to exclude more than one item though.

Right now have

```
 <cfset counter = 1 />
 <cfoutput query="dir1">
 <cfif !listfindNoCase( 'Thumbs.db,2. Electric Accounts Tracking Report.xls,1. Electric Accounts Performance Analytics.xls', dir1.name) > 
<a href="/091_AU20100226/020_Cost_Analyses/010_Electric/Flatten_Files/#dir1.name#" target="_blank">
#dir1.name#</a><br /> 
<cfset counter++ /> </cfif> </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `listFind()` or `listFindNoCase()`.

```
<cfif !listfindNoCase( 'Thumbs.db,otherFile.txt',  dir.name) >
...do stuff...
</cfif>
```

Comment: Then if I am using #CurrentRow# how can I have it not count skipped entries

Comment: What does `#CurrentRow#` have to do with the question you asked?

Comment: If you need a counter you simply use `<cfset counter = 1 />` before your loop and then use `<cfset counter++ />` inside the `cfif` above

Comment: The listfind no case has allowed me to exclude some files. Then I am displaying them and counting them.

Comment: Put the `<cfset counter=1>` before the loop (`cfoutput` in this case) otherwise with each iteration, you are setting it to 1.

Comment: @MichaelDowney - Large blocks of un-formatted code are hard to read. Better to post it as an [update](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23664217/104223), so you can format it. Then delete the comments.